# Is there a way of adding an exit button in a form in oracle forms builder 10g

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

i want to add an exit button(on-button-pressed or on-button-click)which will allow a user to close and exit the form.i do not know how to start.Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Forms already have it in the standard toolbar; why would you want to create yet another button for the same purpose?

Anyway:

- create a button
- create its `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger
- put this into it:

  ```
  exit_form;
  ```
- it'll exit the form, with some exceptions:

  - if you were in query mode, it'll just exit query mode (so you'll have to push the button once again to exit the form)
  - if there were unsaved changes in the form, you'll be prompted to either save or discard those changes
  - there are *rollback* and *commit* modes you can use with that built-in; read more about them in Forms Online Help System.